# Using multiprocessing in python script with Django models

Tags: python, django, sqlite, multiprocessing

I am writing a custom script to run multiple instances of the same functions using multiprocessing with django models.

The code which concerns this post consists of:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for count, script in enumerate(scripts):
        for counter in range(0, len(counters)):
            p = Process(target=script, args=(counters[counter][count],))
            p.start()
            p.join()
```

the loops execute correctly, but I am having a problem with the `__name__ == '__main__'` statement. I could hack it together to say `__name__=__main__` before that line, but then I would run into a problem where `p.start()` throws an error for:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function nordstrom_script at 0x0000000003B2A208>: it's not            found as __main__.nordstrom_script
```

I am relatively new to python/django and have never experimented with multiprocessing before, so please excuse my lack of knowledge if something is dreadfully wrong with my logic.

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated. I know that django does not work well with multiprocessing, and the problem comes from me using:

```
>>>python manage.py shell
>>>execscript('scripts/script.py')
```

and not

```
>>>python scripts/script.py
```

Comment: Is `nordstrom_script` one of the elements of the `scripts` list? Is `nordstrom_script` defined in the same module as the sample code you include in the question?

Comment: @dano yes it is. The other code which might come in handy is `scripts = [nordstrom_script, zappos_script]

counters = [
    [3350000, 7000000],
    [3450000, 7100000],
    [3550000, 7200000],
    [3650000, 7300000],
    [3750000, 7400000],
    [3850000, 7500000],
    [3950000, 7600000],
]
`

Answer (score 1):

This version is directly runnable, and works for me. Could you modify this code to produce the same error?  Note that it only processes the 1st arg of 'counters', I assume this is by design.

### source

```
import multiprocessing 

def produce(arg):
    print 'arg:',arg

scripts = [produce]
counters = [     [3350000, 7000000] ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for count, script in enumerate(scripts):
        for counter in range(0, len(counters)):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(
                target=script, args=(counters[counter][count],)
                )
            p.start()
            p.join()
```

### output

```
arg: 3350000
```

Comment: I have since switched to django-celery. It was a conflict with django itself, so I figured I was better off switching.